# Is it possible to implement both scala.collection.Seq[T] and java.util.List[T] in one class

Tags: java, scala, collections

I'm writing a library in Scala that I'd like to be natural to use from both Scala and Java. I thought it might be possible to write a class that extends `scala.collection.IndexedSeq[T]` and implements `java.util.List[T]`. I was able to deal with the conflict on the `iterator` method by creating a class that implements `scala.collection.Iterator` and `java.util.Iterator` but am stymied by the error

> name clash between inherited members:
>   `def contains(x$1: Any): Boolean` in trait List and
>   `def contains[A1 >: T](elem: A1): Boolean` in trait SeqLike
>   have same type after erasure: `(x$1: Object)Boolean`

Is there any way to work around this error? The method implementations *would* be the same, so it's actually okay that they erase to the same type. Should I just give up this fool's errand and use implicit conversions and just deal with allocation overhead?

Comment: Maybe you can use `java.util.AbstractList<T>` and adapt the scala list and vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

It *might* be possible, but it's a lot of work, and some dirty operations can be involved.

You can't implement both types in Scala, because the Scala compiler is type safe.
The Java compiler however, can still deal with leaving out generic type parameters.

So this is my proposal for a plan -- with no guarantee that it will work:

- Create a Java class that *extends* a concrete Scala collection type, such as `ArrayBuffer` and *implements* `java.util.List`.
- Leave out all generic type parameters.
- Make a Scala `object` that has a factory method which returns `ArrayBuffer[T] with java.util.List[T]`.
- The factory method creates an instance of the class mentioned in the first step, and casts it to the return type.

While trying that out, my IntelliJ IDEA became extremely slow -- presumably because of the enormous type hierarchy of the Scala collection types.
So I could not really test this.

Note that this might be opening up the gates to who knows what strange errors.
I would definitely not recommend this!

Also, in Scala, you always have to declare the type as `ArrayBuffer[T] with java.util.List[T]`, for which you should define a type alias.

I will give you a skeleton here.

First the Java class skeleton, with `UnsupportedOperationException`s for you to fill out:

```
import scala.collection.generic.Subtractable;
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

class MySeqList extends ArrayBuffer implements List {
public static abstract class SeqListIterator implements Iterator, scala.collection.Iterator {
}

@Override
public Subtractable repr() {
    return (Subtractable)super.repr();
}

public boolean add(Object e) {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
public Object get(int i) {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
public Object set(int i, Object e) {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
public void add(int i, Object e) {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
public Object remove(int i) {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
public int indexOf(Object o) {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
public void clear() {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
public boolean addAll(int i, Collection collection) {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
public SeqListIterator iterator() {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
public ListIterator listIterator() {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
public ListIterator listIterator(int i) {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
public List subList(int i, int i1) {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
public boolean equals(Object o) {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
public int hashCode() {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
protected void removeRange(int i, int i1) {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
public int size() {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
public boolean isEmpty() {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
public boolean contains(Object o) {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
public Object[] toArray() {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
public Object[] toArray(Object[] ts) {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
public boolean remove(Object o) {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
public boolean containsAll(Collection collection) {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
public boolean addAll(Collection collection) {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
public boolean removeAll(Collection collection) {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
public boolean retainAll(Collection collection) {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
public String toString() {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
}
```

Now comes the Scala `object`:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

object SeqList {
  def apply[T]():ArrayBuffer[T] with java.util.List[T] = new MySeqList().asInstanceOf[ArrayBuffer[T] with java.util.List[T]]
}
```

I want to emphasize again that this is enormously smelly code.
It doesn't look like a good solution.
You might run into all kinds of trouble implementing the methods. Not sure if you will encounter any blockers in that.

I just tried this out to explore the boundaries of Scala/Java interoperability, for fun.